# Calendar in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, calendar

I would like to create a excel timesheet and upon selecting Nov 2019 from the drop down list, the day of the week will appear correctly against a column of days from 1-31. Can this be possible? Thanks.

[image]

Under Overtime Category if i don't input any start time, it shall not output 0 values, anyway to remove them?

Under Off-In Lieu category, the hours are only take into account when it is beyond 9pm. How can i remove those ### or 0 values?

Comment: *Can this be possible?* Of course. Build a date from entered year-month and column number (or header value) as a day, and format as a weekday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. I'm assuming that the days (1-31) are simply "hard-coded" into a column.  The only variable is changing the Month and Year from a drop-down.
2. The drop-down is encoded as Month and Year, which Excel normally represents as the 1st of that month (e.g. November 2019 is stored as 11/1/2019).  The display may state "November 2019", but the value should be stored internally as a date.
3. The below formulas assume that the drop-down is in `A1` and the days start in `A3`.

Given the above assumptions, you can use this formula to get the day of the week as a number, Sunday = 1.

```vb
=WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),A3))
```

If you want the name of the day as text, you can use the following.  The first gives the first 3 letters of the day.

```vb
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),A3)),"ddd")
```

The second gives the full name of the day.

```vb
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),A3)),"dddd")
```

**EDIT:** Sample output is below

[image]

Comment: i had prepared a table based on your inputs. I had input new queries pertaining to the excel table. Hope you can kindly help, thanks.

Comment: To answer your 2 follow-on questions, my rule of thumb is that using a formula will give you full control of the output.  If you are using a formula, use `IF` and just output a blank string "" if you don't want anything to be displayed.  If a formula is not possible, use the Display format of the cells to hide "0" values.  Without seeing the exact details of your sheet, there's no easy way to understand how you can hide 0 values from the display.